# Пропадает перенос строки при отправке текста из RichTextBox C#

Tags: c#, richtextbox

В поле RichTextBox вывожу текст с переносом строки. Текст выводится правильно, с новой строки. После отправляю этот текст из RichTextBox на почту, перенос строк пропадает именно из этого блока:

```
if (newM.Name != null)
{
     if (newM.Name.short != null) 
     {
           rTB_Parse.Text += Environment.NewLine + "qwe" + " = " + newM.Name.short + " ";
     }
     if (newM.Name.full != null) 
     {
           rTB_Parse.Text += Environment.NewLine + "ert" + " = " + newM.Name.full + " ";
     }
     if (newM.Name.date != null) 
     {
           rTB_Parse.Text += Environment.NewLine + "ghh" + " = " + newM.Name.date + " ";
     }
}
```

....

```
email.Body = rTB_Parse.Text;
```

Comment: Для примера я укоротила текст в кавычках "qwe", "ert", "ghh" и перенос строки перестал пропадать, но как только ввожу текст длиннее "Краткое наименование организации"  - перенос строки пропадает. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: А "пропадает" не в Outlook? а то он любит убирать "лишние" разрывы строк: http://joxi.ru/l2ZvPo0SwL6We2.jpg

Comment: @Zufir, да, отправляю письмо в Outlook, только не показывает это уведомление. Самое интересное, что если я поставлю подряд два переноса строк, он так и сделает, а с одним не работает.

Comment: а если отправить на какой-нибудь условный яндекс? там как?

Comment: @Zufir, увидела я это уведомление, если на него нажать, то он восстанавливает разрывы

Comment: Может выставить email.IsBodyHtml = false; перед email.Body = rTB_Parse.Text;

Answer (score 0):

может так попробовать ???

```
rTB_Parse.Text += "\r\n" + "qwe" + " = " + newM.Name.short + " ";
```

Comment: ранее пробовала этот вариант, не помогло...

Comment: значит нужно проверить - помещается ли ваша длинная строка в границы того поля или контейнера  , в которое вы ее вставляете , вставьте короткие строки через начало строки , а потом более длинные , и посмотрите что будет , если короткие будут нормально отображаться а длинные нет , значит что то с границами контейнера

Comment: да, помещается, я вывожу в richTextBox, ни одна строка не обрывается.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что RichTextBox заменяет все `\r\n` на `\n`. Это его стандартное поведение. И кажется, переучить его нельзя.

Попробуйте сделать вот так:

```
email.Body = rTB_Parse.Text.Replace("\n", "\r\n");
```

Скорее всего, увидите желаемый результат. Хотя решение, конечно, костыльное.

Comment: не работает....

Comment: @Наталия жаль. Я думал, именно это заставляет Аутлук, считать переносы строк лишними. Других версий у меня нет.